# how to schedule reindex of catalog_category_product only

Tags: magento2.2, reindex, product-reindexing

I need to run separately with its own schedule the reindexing of:

> catalog_category_product 
>   catalog_product_category
>   catalog_category_flat

I dont find the in any crontab.xml

How can we do this?
Thanks

Comment: do you mean, you want to run these 3 repetedly after some amount of time?

Comment: yes, and not anymore as part of the current, default, reindex processes..

Comment: create separate cron job with magento command as per your requirement

Comment: @HardikVisa But then i am adding a new cron for that index, not changing the schedule of the index in question right?

Answer (score 1):

You can also create your own cron file and schedule with your specific time.

Create crontab.xml file here

> app/code/YourModule/YourNamespace/etc/crontab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job instance="YourModule\YourNamespace\Cron\CronIndexing" method="execute" name="yourmodulename_cron_indexing_cronjob">
            <schedule>10 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

Above cron is run every 10 mins.

Now create a CRON class file

Create CronIndexing.php file here

> app/code/YourModule/YourNamespace/Cron/CronIndexing.php

```
<?php

namespace YourModule\YourNamespace\Cron;

use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class CronIndexing
{
    protected $logger;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory
     */
    protected $_indexerFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_indexerCollectionFactory;


    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory $indexerFactory,
        \Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory $indexerCollectionFactory
    )
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->_indexerFactory = $indexerFactory;
        $this->_indexerCollectionFactory = $indexerCollectionFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $indexerCollection = $this->_indexerCollectionFactory->create();
        $ids = $indexerCollection->getAllIds();
        foreach ($ids as $id) {
            $idx = $this->_indexerFactory->create()->load($id);
            $idx->reindexAll($id);
        }
        $this->logger->info('Successfully Reindexing');
    }
}
```

> If not affecting anything after adding above files so please run below commands and try again:
>
> 1. php bin/magento cron:install
> 2. php bin/magento cron:run

Comment: well, with this i would be running them at specific times, but not avoiding them to run in the default reindexing, right? It is about reconfiguring the indexes in question, not adding more of them.

Comment: Yes you're right @user968865